# Call function in component I have extended from that has the same name in Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to know if there is an equivalent in vue2 for javascript super().

In javascript I can do this I can do this:

```
class Foo {
    doSomething () {
        return 'Foo';
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    doSomething () {
        return 'Bar';
    }

    callSuper () {
        return Super.doSomething(); 
    }
}

console.log(Bar.callSuper()); // Foo
```

However in Vue2 i can't get access to the original components functions with the same name.

Foo.vue

```
<script>
    export default Foo {
        extends: Component,
        methods: {
            doSomething () {
               return 'Foo';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Bar.vue

```
<template>
    <div><span> {{ callFoo }} </span></div> // Doesn't work
</template>

<script>
    export default Bar {
        extends: Foo,
        methods: {
            doSomething () {
               return 'Bar';
            },

            callFoo () {
                return Super.doSomething(); // Doesn't work, expecting 'Foo'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I took a look in the documentation and didn't see anything similar. Is there a way to achieve this easily or should I change my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think mixins will achieve what you're looking for.

A mixin is a vue component, without the template. It supports all the properties a normal component does, methods, computed, data, lifecycle hooks etc. You can then import your common methods (or whatever) into your normal vue components

define your mixin as an object, containing your common logic.

```
export const myCommonMixin = {
  methods: {
    someCommonMethod () {
      ..do something
    }
  }
}
```

then import it into your Bar component

```
import { myCommonMixin } from '../mixins/myMixins'
export default Bar {
  mixins: [
    commonMixin
  ],
  methods: {
    callFoo () {
      return this.someCommonMethod()
    }
  }
}
```

In your Bar component, you have access to anything defined in your mixin(s) using the `this` keyword

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-mixin

Comment: Yes this could achieve what I'm after however I'm more looking for something that is component specific to a certain type of components.

Comment: No reason why you can’t use the mixin on just those components

Comment: Looking back at this a few weeks later this solution is the easiest way to achieve a similar output.